# Database running on IIS port 8080 accessible locally on server but not when connecting externally without VPN

Tags: windows, iis, port

I have an IIS server that has a Database system (Universe) that runs on port 8080 and when I access the port using "localhost:8080" or when connected to company vpn "Servername:8080".
I can see data on both of these ports.
I have an angular application running as the default on port 80 and it calls the database port 8080.

The angular application loads up when accessing externally from any computer (after login) on "websitename/angular" but I can't access my database data from the angular application and neither can I access the database externally using a variety of urls "websitename:8080" etc..

I've obviously set something up wrong or not at all, my firewalls on the IIS server are all disabled.

My question is how would I be able to access the data on port 8080 through the public website name and while not being connected to a VPN.

(The database does not store anything locally its fetching the data from another IIS server so I haven't been able to set up site bindings)

Please let me know your thoughts or any advice and if there is any further information you need please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot reach yourwebsite:8080 from your public network, but only with your VPN connected, it's probably because the 8080tcp port is not forwarded to public network, you may need to make a rule on your perimeter firewall.